# Shelving unit for shed

Tags: shed, shelving, storage

I have recently bought a 12x8 ft shed. It has been assembled and ready for use. I am thinking about how to improve the storage area inside it. This shall require getting shelves.

I am thinking of buying something which looks like this:
[image]

The questions are as follows:

1. Is this suitable to be put into shed?
2. How is this supposed to be tied to the shed wall so it is safe (not prone to topple)  without damagining the shed itself?
3. Its feet are going to have a large pressure due to weight of everything on the shelf and the shelving system itself. Can this damage the shed floor?

EDIT:

The shed where this is going to be used is from UK brand "Forest" and is titled "Timberdale Tongue & Groove Pressure Treated 12×8 Reverse Apex Shed – Double Door". The description on the website is as follows:
This extra large 12x8 Reverse Apex Workshop is a premium quality building with a great specification. The dimensions of the building make it ideal for use as a workshop, double doors with plenty of room for a workbench, chair, shelving and storage of large items and double windows for extra light. The strong solid timber Tongue & Groove floor means that storage of heavier items and floor-standing shelving is not a problem. Packed with high quality features and specifications.

- Premium Pressure Treated Timberdale Tongue & Groove 12x8 Reverse Apex Double Door Workshop from Forest
- Highest quality Tongue & Groove construction
- Robust Tongue & Groove boarded floor with supporting Pressure Treated floor bearers
- 2 opening windows with 4mm Toughened Safety Glass
- Double doors with diagonal double "Z" framing for strength
- High quality rim lock door latch supplied for security
- 12mm Tongue & Groove boarded roof with red mineral felt
- Pressure Treated with a 15 year Anti-Rot guarantee
- Made in the UK from FSC® certified timber
- Modular construction for easier handling & assembly
- Double Framing

[image: shed]

Comment: Can you provide more details about the shed walls and floor?

Comment: For the floor, a one or two pieces of plywood/OSB 4x8s 3/4 inch thick will spread the weight over a larger area.  For tying, are there any bolts holding the shed pieces together?

Comment: Please ask just question per post. Suitability depends on usage and opinion, so you decide that. \

Comment: What are you planning to store in your shed that makes you so concerned about the weight?

Comment: One thing to watch with those screwless clip-together shelves: they don't have much rigidity - they can easily wobble and lean. They can benefit from additional diagonal bracing to keep them rigid - or buy better shelves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this suitable to be put into shed?

depends. from the picture it looks like the frame of the shelving unit is metal and the shelves are from plywood or something. if so then the factor that plays a role is humidity (eg. where the shed is located / what's the environment of the surrounding area). if the humidity is high then the raw metallic frame will corrode if it is not treated (painted, pickled, galvanized, etc). plywood issue is the same if it's raw... it can soak in the humidity which will expand its volume, deform, rot or even break the frame. so we are back to the shed and its insulation capabilities. if the localization of the shed is dry then you are ok even with the raw shelving unit.

> How is this supposed to be tied to the shed wall so it is safe (not prone to topple) without damagining the shed itself?

you have two options. either shelf your stuff smartly - heavy stuff on the bottom and light stuff on top. or you can anchor the shelving unit to your shed for example with something like:

[image]

or even:

[image]

where you need only two of these installed like:

[image]

or directly anchor it through the frame with pair of:

[image]

this should even withstand an earthquake (if your shed will)

> Its feet are going to have a large pressure due to weight of everything on the shelf and the shelving system itself. Can this damage the shed floor?

also depends. if you use the shelving unit like a normal person (eg. not overweight it with weight 3x the allowed limit) then you are ok. but you can always improve it with some high-tech boosted hard rubber mat with integrated AI like:

[image]

or just grab two boards and place them under the feet like:

[image]

to enlarge the surface area of those tiny feet for better weight distribution

Comment: Can't up-vote with "high-tech rubber floor mat with boosted AI" there; that's making no sense to me, nor does it seem as good a solution as a bit of plywood.

Comment: @keshlam np. it's just a hard rubber mat with antivibration capability - no big deal. ppl tend to use them for this purpose or even for the whole floor if they have money to spare. they can withstand heavy weights from working tables, machines even closets within garages, sheds, storage units, etc. advantage is that they can serve even as insulation when standing on them in winter

Comment: @gnicko np either. the rubber granulate of these mats is hardened and designed to withstand heavy loads. they can be used in various conditions - exterior, interior, in rain, sun, in cold (from -30 to +140°C). do not confuse them with those regular mats used in front of the entrance to the house for wiping the does before entering - those are different and soft. looks like they are probably not spread on all continents.

Comment: @gnicko here you go:  [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlsFf.jpg), 
  [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNiVY.png), 
  [link3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdyGA.png), 
  [link4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPjVj.png), 
  [link5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0ewu.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

I think you could set up the shelf unit as it comes "out of the box" without having to do too much else to it. Since it's a shed, moisture may be a problem with metal shelving (rust) so you may want to consider wood or even plastic to get past that problem.

You'll want to evaluate the shelving unit to ensure that it can handle the weights you're intending to store on it, but as long as the weight requirements are not excessive, the floor of the shed should hold it. You can add a section of plywood or planks under the shelf uprights to distribute the weight if it's a concern.

You'll want to make sure that your shed is level, etc and that should be the largest part of avoiding the shelves from tipping over. You'll need to put the heaviest items on the bottom shelf, of course.

If you want to secure the shelving unit to the wall you should be able to drive screws through the uprights into the studs if the uprights line up with them. If not, you can attach wood cross-wise across the studs and attach the shelving unit to that.

You could solve both problems by building custom shelves attached to the walls as well. That might be more useful for you in the long run.

Comment: Won't be it too expensive to install shelves attached to the shed wall that are cut to the correct size? I believe that shelves that are attached to the shed walls can hold less weight than the thing I am trying to buy. I believe this because the shed walls are made of wood pieces that are held together by screws unlike concrete walls. Is this belief correct?

Comment: Most houses in the US are made of wood pieces that are held together by nails. Wood can be stronger than you might expect

Comment: You could add "legs" to the front of the shelves if you're still concerned about weight, but I'd think that properly constructed wood shelves could hold much more weight than the shelving you included a picture of.

Comment: @quantum231  If we have someone ask a question about hanging/mounting heavy objects to a wall, we always suggest screwing into the studs(wall uprights).  Your shed seems to have studs in the picture, so only need shelf brackets made for the weight.